# create order with different extra bag for outbound and inbound

Tags: amadeus

I want to test order create API by adding extra bags. And I am experiencing a strange problem.

I make a search for Paris-NYC round trip, then I send the request to offer price API using `include=detailed-fare-rules,bags` parameter.

In the response, I get 2 kinds of extra bag information:

- 1 bag, 30 EUR
- 2 bags, 75 EUR

```
"bags": {
      "1": {
        "quantity": 1,
        "name": "CHECKED_BAG",
        "price": {
          "amount": "30.00",
          "currencyCode": "EUR"
        },
        "bookableByItinerary": true,
        "segmentIds": [
          "1",
          "3"
        ],
        "travelerIds": [
          "1"
        ]
      },
      "2": {
        "quantity": 2,
        "name": "CHECKED_BAG",
        "price": {
          "amount": "75.00",
          "currencyCode": "EUR"
        },
        "bookableByItinerary": true,
        "segmentIds": [
          "1",
          "3"
        ],
        "travelerIds": [
          "1"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Everything goes well if I create order by:

- adding 1 bag for outbound(paris to NYC), and adding 1 bag for inbound(NYC to Paris)
- adding only 1 bag for outbound (0 extra bag for inbound)
- adding 2 bag for outbound(paris to NYC), and adding 2 bags for inbound(NYC to Paris)

The problem is for the scenario:

I create order by adding 1 bag for outbound, and adding 2 bags for inbound.
In this case, the order is created with a warning message

```
"warnings": [
    {
      "status": 200,
      "code": 0,
      "title": "BookingWithPriceMarginWarning",
      "detail": "The prices are lower than expected"
    }
  ]
```

And the created order contains 1 extra bag for outbound, and 1 extra bag for inbound.

So I have 2 questions about this strange problem:

- Is it normal that my order is modified when processing order create ?
- Adding different number of extra bags for different itineraries is supported ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

***Is it normal that my order is modified when processing order create ?***

It depends if you are Self-Service or Enterprise user:

- For Enterprise users, Flight Create Orders offer the possibility to do a "best-effort" for additional-service booking. If this option is activated, Flight Create Orders gives priority to the reservation of your flight and remove the additional service that cannot be booked. That's why you receive the warning in your request when it happens.
- Self Service users have the default behavior which rejects the creation of the order if at least one additional service can not be booked. In this case you will receive the following error:

```
 {
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 400,
      "code": 38034,
      "title": "ONE OR MORE SERVICES ARE NOT AVAILABLE",
      "detail": "Error booking additional services"
    }
  ]
}
```

***Adding different number of extra bags for different itineraries is supported ?***

Yes, that is supported. Be aware that you cannot have an infinite amount of bag on a plane, so it could happen that you get an error when adding extra bags if there are too many bags already added by other passengers.

Comment: thanks for your response. But it is strange because we are using self-service, and Flight Create Orders still gives priority to the reservation of flight by removing the additional service that cannot be booked.

Comment: then I don't understand why the additional service cannot be booked for my test scenario: add 1 extra bag for outbound, and add 2 extra bags for inbound. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Hi @Xin. That is weird. We would need extra information to trace the problem. Would you mind to share with us the request you sent, the timestamp and the AmadeusRequestId header that comes in the response? You can send it to developers@amadeus.com. Thanks!